# How to make a paragraph NOT wrap around an image in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2013

If I have an image with some text wrapping around it, how can I set a paragraph/style to NOT wrap around the image. See image below:

[image: text wrapping break]

The "text wrapping break" doesn't quite work for two reasons:

1. I cannot create a style for it and I need to manually insert a break (show in red).
2. It is really a line break, not a paragraph break. So if I have something like a bullet point for a list, the bullet stays with the original paragraph besides the image and the text starts below the image (shown in blue).

I need something like `clear` in CSS, that just moves the new paragraph to below everything that is floating around.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there is not a method built-in to Word that will do what you want using a Style or any other paragraph setting.

What can be done though is setup a 2-column, single row table shell and save the shell as `AutoText` so you can pop it in when needed. Then use the `Pictures insert` function on the `Insert tab`, placing the image in cell one and corresponding text in cell two. Make sure on the table shell that the `Table Options Property to Automatically Resize to Fit Content` is turned Off. This will then autosize the inserted image to the predetermined width of cell one.

Below is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right justify the image, and Left justify the text. Or vise versa. Depending upon the look (flow) you desire. More specifically; Highlight the Image, then choose the Justification you desire. Then highlight the Text, and select the *opposite* Justification. Beware of undesired Line Breaks that might interfere with your desired result (Text, and Content **flow**).

Comment: I reviewed my question and added a image to ilustrate my point.

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me:

- Write paragraphs next to the image
- Insert a text-wrapping break as soon as you want further content to exist *below* the image
- Insert a non-breaking space using `ctrl`+`shift`+`space`, so that at least one character occupies the last line of the paragraph which exists below the image
- Set the font size of the non-breaking space to 1
- Set the "after" spacing of the paragraph to 0
- Press `enter` to achieve a new paragraph immediately below the now-miniscule line below the image

The 1-sized space after a wrapping-break creates nearly identical behavior to CSS' `clear` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a partial answer for some situations and doesn't regard the sub-question about styles.

To avoid having the bullet or list number on the wrapping break you can insert a paragraph end before the break. This will introduce some extra whitespace when the text that should be wrapped actually spans the area of the image. This is only slightly better than nothing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).